# wordpress : call ajax in the button click

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

issue : 
- Calling ajax request and write text in the html .

problem : 
- the first time when calling ajax and write the values in the div successfully
- the second time the ajax get the data (in the page source ) but the values in the div doesn't change although the cache: false . 
- i try to generate random number to show the issue well.

Code:

1-Ajax call :

```
$("#Finish").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         async: true,
         url: document.location.origin + "/air/ajaxCalls.php",
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
         data: {
             ajaxType: "Finish",
             examid: 1,
             index: 2,
             qid: <? php echo $currentquestion ?> ,
             ansid: $('#tags').val(),
         },
         success: function (data) {
             //    alert("success");
             if (data) {
                 //    alert(data.status); 
                 // $("questiontext").html("next question");
                 // alert("data");
                 // alert('empty')

                 $('#tags').val("");

                 document.getElementById('questiontext').innerHTML = "<p>" + "<?php echo mt_rand() . getQuesName($currentquestion) . rand(); ?>" + "</p>";
                 document.getElementById('answerstext').innerHTML = "<?php getAnswers($currentquestion); ?>"

                 $("#questiontext").html("<?php echo mt_rand()?>");

                 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
                     $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
                 });

                 $('#check1').click(function () {});
                 $('#choose1, #check1').click(function () {
                     $('#check1').click();
                 });

                 $('#check2').click(function () {});
                 $('#choose2, #check2').click(function () {
                     $('#check2').click();
                 });

                 $('#check3').click(function () {});
                 $('#choose3, #check3').click(function () {
                     $('#check3').click();
                 });

                 $('#check4').click(function () {});
                 $('#choose4, #check4').click(function () {
                     $('#check4').click();
                 });

                 function Populate() {
                     vals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {
                         return this.value;
                     }).get().join(',');
                     // console.log(vals);
                     $('#tags').val(vals);
                 }

                 $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
                     Populate()
                 }).change();



                 if (data.status == 1) { ///sucess
                     alert('answer inserted');
                 }

             } else {
                 alert("Error : Please try again");
                 return false;
                 // no data found
             }
         },
         error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Error : " + errorThrown);
         }
     });

 });
```

2 - receive calls:

```
 if ($_POST['ajaxType'] == "Finish") {
     echo json_encode(array("status" => 1));
 }
```

3- div (html)

```
<div id="questiontext">
    <p>

    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not routing through wordpress ajax?

Comment: i search for example with wordpress ajax to do similar to my work but i dont find it .
(i need make ajax to update the div content )

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue a couple days ago.  The issue is that in your AJAX call:

```
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     async: true,
     url: document.location.origin + "/air/ajaxCalls.php",
     dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,
     data: {
         ajaxType: "Finish",
         examid: 1,
         index: 2,
         qid: <? php echo $currentquestion ?> ,
         ansid: $('#tags').val(),
     },
```

Change your url to the main wordpress AJAX file.  Usually it can be found in the /wp-admin/ folder of your website.  Once you change the URL from

```
document.location.origin + "/air/ajaxCalls.php"
```

to

```
../../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Go into your main function file and add a new AJAX call.  For example, create something like this:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_populate", "populate");

function(populate){
 if (data) {
             //    alert(data.status); 
             // $("questiontext").html("next question");
             // alert("data");
             // alert('empty')

             $('#tags').val("");

             document.getElementById('questiontext').innerHTML = "<p>" + "<?php echo mt_rand() . getQuesName($currentquestion) . rand(); ?>" + "</p>";
             document.getElementById('answerstext').innerHTML = "<?php getAnswers($currentquestion); ?>"

             $("#questiontext").html("<?php echo mt_rand()?>");

             $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
                 $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
             });

             $('#check1').click(function () {});
             $('#choose1, #check1').click(function () {
                 $('#check1').click();
             });

             $('#check2').click(function () {});
             $('#choose2, #check2').click(function () {
                 $('#check2').click();
             });

             $('#check3').click(function () {});
             $('#choose3, #check3').click(function () {
                 $('#check3').click();
             });

             $('#check4').click(function () {});
             $('#choose4, #check4').click(function () {
                 $('#check4').click();
             });

             function Populate() {
                 vals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {
                     return this.value;
                 }).get().join(',');
                 // console.log(vals);
                 $('#tags').val(vals);
             }

             $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
                 Populate()
             }).change();



             if (data.status == 1) { ///sucess
                 alert('answer inserted');
             }

         } else {
             alert("Error : Please try again");
             return false;
             // no data found
         }
     },
}
```

Now you have your populate function in your functions.php file rather than your jquery file.  This makes it so all you have to do with your AJAX call is specify the action you want to preform.  This ammounts to adding

```
"action":"populate",
```

into your data array.

Hopefully this helps out a bit, let me know if I can clarify more.

Comment: the problem still appear :
1- change the url to ../../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.
2 - put the function in admin-ajax.php . 
3- i don't know how to separate the function populate . 

in the first its popup ("Error : Please try again")
the i comment if(data) ,but the problem still accrue.

Comment: "2 - put the function in admin-ajax.php"
-You need to put the functions in functions.php, not admin-ajax.php

Does this fix the rest of the errors?  I don't quite understand what you mean in your point 3.  Please elaborate?